# Sending Two Simple Product To Add To Cart In Single Woocommerce Button Click

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding two different products in my website and they both combines together to form one single product, what i am trying to achieve is that when i click on the add to cart button, I want to send two product id's to "add to cart" which means two different products, one is the page from where the a"dd to cart" is clicked and the second one is manual product id which i've assigned to hidden text box.

I tried the ajax call but that didn't work. Also I don't want to go with woocommerce paid extensions for bundle products and other types.

So it would be great if i can make some changes to add to cart.

Comment: "I tried the ajax call but that didn't work." Always show what you tried. "I don't want to go with woocommerce paid extensions for bundle products and other types." if they do exactly what you want why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple, like "Woocommerce Free Gift" plugin, there is a free version as well. You can setup automatic product add to cart on certain circumstances.

Otherwise, you need to modify your functions.php, whenever you are adding "product A" -> add "product B". Something likes this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
 if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = ID_OF_PRODUCT_A;
    $product_b = ID_OF_PRODUCT_B;
    $found = false;

    if( $woocommerce->cart->total > 0 ) {
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if (  $found )
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_b );
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Oliver thanks, for the help i did managed to add both products at the same time. I did the ajax call for the first and then then made a click event to add to cart button and it did work.. However I'll try the suggestion that you've made.

Comment: Also any idea on how can i move my variation drop down postition, i mean adding it right below the thumbnail images or anywhere in the page.

Comment: this is another question, please submit it :) it will need some more details as well.

Comment: if my suggestion will work our, I would appreciate acceptance of the answer

Comment: Hi Oliver, unfortunately i didn't tried this, as i found another way to resolve my problem, instead of adding another product i simply took its attributes along with price and added to my cart and the final product will have the main product along with specification of other one. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: however now i got stuck with wordpress ajax pagination do you have any idea on how to resolve, i can do it with simple sql query but not with the wp_query results.

Comment: Better post another question with more details so everybody could see it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108948/ajax-pagination-with-wordpress-query here is the link